# Writing and saving image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have written a program that captures a frame from an avi format movie and saves it in JPEG format in the C:\ Directory. I don't get any error when I run my program but when I go to the C:\ directory to find the JPEG file, the file is not even there.
What have I done wrong? I get the same problem while writing a video file in avi format. I just can't find the file in the directory.

here is my code

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap("C:\\airbus.avi");
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,200);
    Mat img;
    cap >> img;

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    compression_params.push_back(100);

    bool bSuccess = imwrite("C:/hello.jpg",img,compression_params);

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't save the file"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        namedWindow("Open",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        Mat openImage = imread("C:\\hello.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        imshow("Open",openImage);
    }

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just try with  imwrite("C:\\hello.jpg",img,compression_params);

Comment: nope, still not working

Comment: Are you able to load the video ? Then try to save in current directory like imwrite("filename.jpg",img);

Comment: Are you sure you actually have an image? I believe it just returns the equivalent of Null (not sure in c) if the image retrieval doesn't work. Can you do an `imshow()` on `img` before saving it? What do you see?

Comment: @ Haris Yep! It worked. I could save the image in the current directory. Thanks a lot. I think I found out the problem. I am such a fool. My C:\ directory needs administrator's permission to bring changes in it. My program works for all other directories. I just have to remove the permission in C:\

Comment: @ Kobejohn yeah the image was being displayed without any error. But the problem was that, I was not able to find the image file in the directory when I was checking it in the C:\ directory manually. But still I don't understand how I could see the image without any error.